# Scraping data from one table column if another column contains target words

Tags: javascript, regex, web-scraping

I would like to search an html table using javascript/jQuery.

If one of the cells contains a certan words which will always be in column five, I want the date from column  one.

I have attached an example of the table I would like to search.

I'm thinking that I have to do a regex on the table and then capture the cell that contains the text?

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="all" border="1" id="dgNoticeAudit" style="border-color:#CCCCCC;width:98%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>21/02/2019 17:32:26</td>
      <td>ImportDocument WS</td>
      <td>EXTCORRES</td>
      <td>CHLGLOG</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">An externally printed NFD document has been imported.</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 13:57:12</td>
      <td>BSPR1R</td>
      <td>NOTE</td>
      <td>CHLGLOG</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Note inserted</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 13:55:57</td>
      <td>BSPR1R</td>
      <td>CANCLLEDT</td>
      <td>CHLGLOG</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Cancelled task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 13:55:57</td>
      <td>BSPR1R</td>
      <td>CLOSEDT</td>
      <td>CHLGLOG</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Closed task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 11:06:21</td>
      <td>bspvxs</td>
      <td>CLOSEDT</td>
      <td>CHLGLOG</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Closed task with Id: TF04562943 - Task type: Enforcement Review Applications</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 11:03:59</td>
      <td>bspvxs</td>
      <td>LOGCHLG</td>
      <td>CHLGLOG</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Challenge logged, reason code: E_SPCIRCUM</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 11:02:46</td>
      <td>bspvxs</td>
      <td>RHOLD</td>
      <td>NFDP</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Release hold</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>19/02/2019 11:02:05</td>
      <td>bspvxs</td>
      <td>HOLD</td>
      <td>NFDP</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Hold info modified - CORROHOLD - Upto Mar 5 2019 </td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>18/02/2019 17:40:07</td>
      <td>CivicaUser</td>
      <td>NEWT</td>
      <td>NFDP</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Created task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter</td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="labelbox" align="center" valign="middle">
      <td>18/02/2019 16:56:02</td>
      <td>CivicaUser</td>
      <td>HOLD</td>
      <td>NFDP</td>
      <td align="left" style="width:250px;">Hold all actions - CORROHOLD - Upto Mar 4 2019 </td>
      <td align="right">0.00</td>
      <td align="right">397.30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show code for an attempt of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the `tr`'s with the following selector `'#dgNoticeAudit tbody tr'` and start extracting the cells from there. Then you can use `.filter` and `String.includes` for filtering the data with your described words contained.

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('#dgNoticeAudit tbody tr');
var data = Array.prototype.map.call(rows, tr => {
    let td = tr.cells[4]; // index 4 for the 5th column
    return td.innerHTML || td.innerText || '';
});

console.log(data);
/* result will be = [
    "An externally printed NFD document has been imported.",
    "Note inserted",
    "Cancelled task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter↵",
    "Closed task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter↵",
    "Closed task with Id: TF04562943 - Task type: Enforcement Review Applications↵",
    "Challenge logged, reason code: E_SPCIRCUM",
    "Release hold",
    "Hold info modified - CORROHOLD - Upto Mar 5 2019 ",
    "Created task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter↵",
    "Hold all actions - CORROHOLD - Upto Mar 4 2019 "
]; */

    const words = 'Closed task'; // Your searching words
    let filteredData = data.filter(sentence => sentence.includes(words));
    console.log(filteredData);
    /*result will be = [
        "Closed task with Id: TF04563335 - Task type: Enforcement Review - Letter↵",
        "Closed task with Id: TF04562943 - Task type: Enforcement Review Applications↵",
    ]*/
```